# Vundle Installation not working

Tags: vim, vundle

Installation Path - also tried it with installing in ~/.vim/bundle which also doesnt work:

[image: Installation Path]

Error Message is 2 sites long - only copied the first site

[image: Error Message]

configured my vimrc like the guide on git said ....

[image: .vimrc File]

Anyone knows what I did wrong?

Comment: Please don't post screenshots. My 2 blind developer friends really hate it.

http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Answer (score 0):

Can be closed as I found the problem - It was a firewall problem - as I didnt git clone, but copied the files into the directory, which seems to miss some needed links/files/whatever